# why do i get reversed doubly linked list?

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

WHY I AM GETTING AN REVERSED DATA OUTPUT= (40->30->20->10->None).
Please solve error:
is there any other way for doubly linked list ?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data,next,prev):
        self.data=data
        self.next=next
        self.prev=prev

class linkedlist:
    head=None
    tail=None
    def show(self):
        current_node=self.tail
        while current_node is not None:
            print(current_node.data,"-->",end=" ")
            current_node=current_node.prev
        #self.tail.next=self.head
        print(None)

    def append(self,data):
        node=Node(data,None,None)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head=self.tail=node
        else:
            node.prev=self.tail
            self.tail.next=node
        self.tail=node
s=linkedlist()
s.append(10)
s.append(20)
s.append(30)
s.append(40)
s.show()
print("Doubly Linked List Output")
```

**Please Solve this error**

Comment: You are traversing from tail node thats why you see the output is in reverse

Comment: So what should I do

Comment: Means what change should I do

Comment: Well, traverse from head if you want it to display as 10,20,30,40. current_node=self.head and also make sure you change this to current_node=current_node.tail.next

Comment: Oh thank buddy but I have a question in doubly linked list does "None" prints?

Comment: what do you mean ? if thats a default value you assign during creation of node then it prints. As you are happy with the comment, I will post it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `show()` method works this way - it starts from tail and goes toward the head of the list. To go from head to tail use:

```
    current_node=self.head 
    while current_node is not None:
        print(current_node.data,"-->",end=" ")
        current_node=current_node.next # NEXT!
```

Answer (score 0):

Please traverse from head if you want it to display as 10,20,30,40. You can change your show method to start with

```
 current_node=self.head
```

and also make sure you change below to

```
 current_node=current_node.next
```

at every iteration.

Comment: Error Node object has no attribute tail

Comment: Nope not working , I have removed print(None) but output is like 10->20->30->40->

Comment: I have to remove that last one -->

Comment: You have to print "-->" based on condition that current_node is not NONE. Because you are printing it along with the data so when it is the last node it prints -->. You have to separate the printing of current_node.data and then if condition and then print "-->" if that is true

Comment: can i create stack using linked list ?